# Bluetooth connection to other External USB Bluetooth devises with out accessory?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, bluetooth, ios6

I have a requirement - I need to connect the my iPhone application with external Bluetooth Devices like (Thermometer, Oximeter) without External Accessory and I need to transfer the data with my application to Bluetooth Device. Is it possible? Can I connect my iPhone to any other devices (not a Apple device)? Is anyone aware of this?

Comment: Bluetooth is not USB. It's not even related.

Comment: Is this question for Bluetooth LE or classic Bluetooth?

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking for connect bluetooth with any other bluetooth than its possible from now.

in ios apple introduce core bluetooth for connect with external bluetooth devices. The CoreBluetooth framework provides access to Bluetooth 4.0 low energy devices. but its support after ios 5.0 .

you can get more information and demo source code for it from below url.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html

hope this will help you.

Comment: ha i have downloaded that code when am going to connect non apple devise and apple both devises are not coonecting so is there any other sample code are else?

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking for connect bluetooth with any other bluetooth than its possible from now.

you have aslo get more information from given below url.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: ha i have downloaded that code when am going to connect non apple devise and apple both devises are not coonecting so is there any other sample code are else?

Comment: i think this is only for apple devices ... u have to try connect apple to apple ....

Comment: but i need to connect to other usb devises like medical devises weighing mechine,thermometer do you have any idea